# Getting permission error using sftp

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, sftp, sshd

I have setup an sftp server on my centos vm.
I created a user `nsftp` within the group `sftp`

```
nsftp:x:16025:16026::/archive:/sbin/nologin
```

I also edited the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /data/%u
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Now, I'm able to successfully login to the sftp shell, but am getting a permission denied error on any read/write operation:

```
Connected to 10.41.70.55.
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:16 I:1
debug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> /archive size 0
sftp> ls
remote readdir("/archive"): Permission denied
sftp> mkdir dirs
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:14 I:3
debug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 3
Couldn't create directory: Permission denied
sftp>
```

The file permissions are as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nsftp sftp 4096 Aug  5 06:04 /data/nsftp/archive
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Aug  5 05:38 /data/nsftp
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Aug  5 05:38 /data
```

Could someone help me debug the issue? Thnx.

Comment: The data directory and the data/nsftp directory are owned by root.  That may be the issue.

Comment: @RandyJohnson Those directories have to have that ownership/permission for the chroot feature to work.

Comment: Just as @Kenster said, I need root permissions on /data and /data/nsftp to properly implement a jailed environment for my sftp directory